# How to use non standard CSS selectors in a CSSResource

Tags: css, gwt, css-selectors

I am trying to use styles for the scrollbars in webkit. The CSS selectors look like this:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:disabled
```

and so on.

When I use those in a ClientBundle as a CSSResource, the compiler is 
complaining about those selectors. This results in warnings during 
compile time, not errors.

But those styles aren't being applied.

I tried to escape the colons, dashes etc. without luck. 
The literal function doesn't apply here either as it is only used in 
combination with values, not selectors.

I also used the `@external` annotation to avoid obfuscation of the 
selectors.

Nothing seems to work.

Has anyone an idea how to get those styles into my ClientBundle?

Greetings, 
Matthias

Comment: Are you using the @NotStrict annotation on your CssResource? http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/resources/client/CssResource.NotStrict.html

Comment: Yes. If I understood correctly, this should only suppress compilation errors when a selector hasn't got a corresponding method in the CssResource Class. But I've just tried it again to make sure, and it didn't help.

Comment: I have a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764010/how-to-make-the-css-selector-work-in-gwt-css-resource), and it seems like the same type of problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Literal function" for non standard CSS definitions http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/CssResource#Literal_function

Comment: This only works for "property values that do not conform to the CSS grammar". I need the same thing, but for selectors. I've tried the literal function on the selectors without luck.