# How to make the CSS "~" selector work in GWT Css Resource

Tags: gwt, css, css-selectors

I realize that the GWT Css resource parser only support CSS2 at the moment, but is there a way to make the css shared parent select (the "~" selector) to work in a Css Resource?

For example:

```
.password{
    font-weight: normal;
}
.email ~ .password{   /* <--- This selector won't be included */
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: the `literal` function works well for styles that CssResource can't understand - I don't know if it works for selectors as well.  You might try `.email literal("~") .password { ... } `, for example.

Comment: I tried a few iterations, but all them result in the selector not being output. I've tried both `.email literal("~") .password` and `literal(".email ~ .password")`

Comment: I've also tried `.email \~ .password`, but that outputs `.email \~ .password`

Comment: Actually [general sibling combinator selector](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#general-sibling-combinators) is in CSS selectors level 4 aka CSS4

Comment: @Mohsen - be that as it may, it has great [cross-browser support](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t30)

Comment: [this questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683039/how-to-use-non-standard-css-selectors-in-a-cssresource) I think is trying to addess the same problem

Comment: @Mohsen: **Actually**, the general sibling combinator was [introduced in level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators), many years back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If worse comes to worst and you don't find an elegant solution to this, you can always inject some styles after compilation.  That is, let CssResource turn `.email` and `.password` into `email()` and `password()`, and then inject `email() + " ~ " + password()` into your page manually.  Clearly an ugly hack, but you'd still get all the benefits of CssResource (except browser-specific tweaking) and the styles should apply as you expect.

I guess the simplest workaround is to create `.email-password-parent` and apply it manually to the parent.